# An error occurred creating the form (activex control/worker thread)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am having an issue using an external component which can be found here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27738/NET-component-that-simplifies-tracking-of-system

The problem I am having is that I want to talk to the main thread (frmMain), but when this takes place *SystemIdleTimer1_OnEnterIdleState* wants to create a new form because of *SystemIdleTimer1* is a different thread.

```
Private Sub SystemIdleTimer1_OnEnterIdleState(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EdinDazdarevic.IdleEventArgs) Handles SystemIdleTimer1.OnEnterIdleState  
    frmMain.stopActiveTimer()

    MessageBox.Show("Entered idle state")
End Sub
```

How can I call data in the main thread in the current scenario?

There are some similar questions on StackOverflow, but I am struggling to tie everything together:

- [Crossthread operation not valid... - VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240702/crossthread-operation-not-valid-vb-net)
- [How do I call a function on the main thread from another thread in vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591114/how-do-i-call-a-function-on-the-main-thread-from-another-thread-in-vb)

Comment: Hmm, that is pretty typical Codeproject.com code, it always omits the "only works on my machine" caution.  Don't use System.Timers.Timer, use the timer from the toolbox.

Comment: After replacing System.Timers with System.Windows.Forms.Timer everything worked as should, thanks!